# Can't access JavaScript variable inside function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm making an extension for selected text search in different search engines. One of the menu items changes if the selected string is a particular one. I have this done so far and it does what I want, except I can not make the "title" of the menu change. How do I give value to the variable "myTitle" in if statement inside the function?

Thanks in advance.

```
var myTitle; // if I give value here it does work, but I need the value based on the if statement bellow.

function myFunction(selectedText) {

    if(selectedText.match (/someString|SomeOtherString/)) {

        var myURL1 = 'https://someURL' + selectedText;
        chrome.tabs.create({url: myURL1});
        myTitle = "title1"; //I can not make the variable to get this value here

    }else{

         var myURL2 = 'https://someOtherURL' + selectedText;
         chrome.tabs.create({url: topicCall});
         myTitle = "title2"; //I can not make the variable to get this value here
         }
    }


chrome.contextMenus.create({
                **"title": myTitle,**  // this should change based on the selection 
                 contexts:["selection"], 
                 onclick: function (info)myFunction(info.selectionText);}                             
                 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You have "cause and effect" mixed up. When `chrome.contextMenus.create` is called, `myFunction` has not executed yet and the value of `myTitle` has not been assigned.

Comment: Dang, don't know how I missed this too. Yeah, if myFunction isn't called it won't ever run!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can use [chrome.contextMenus.update](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-update), after the page is loaded.  You could create the menu, with default titles, but with unique IDs.  Then use the above method, based on whatever the "selectedText" is, and use the IDs to replace the titles.